# Transparent texture framebuffer (OpenGL ES 2)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I am new to FBOs and this issue has been driving me nuts for hours. I am interested in finding a solution to what I'm asking rather than an alternative. This is on Android.

I'm creating a framebuffer, then I'm drawing a circle to the texture attached to it. Then I'm drawing that texture to the default framebuffer like it's a regular texture. All is wonderful and displays as expected...

... except for the fact that the texture is completely opaque not only where I'm drawing the circle. I want all other areas to be transparent and only the circle part of the texture to be visible. More precisely, what I want to 'fill' my texture with transparent pixels, then draw my circle over them, then render this texture to the default framebuffer and be able to see what's behind it. **How can I do that? Is it even possible?** Or maybe there's a way to keep my texture opaque and tell OpenGL not to render, say, the black pixels from it?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112779/transparent-framebuffer-background-in-opengl), but the checked answer doesn't help. The comment underneath it suggests using `glClear` (I assume it refers to `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`), but I did that after every `glBindFramebuffer` and it still did nothing. I also read about enabling alpha blending, so I did `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` after every `glBindFramebuffer` and my texture stayed opaque.

The other answer suggests it's platform dependent, so I'm looking for an Android solution.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, anyone can help ? 
@async it's been a long since you posted this question. Did you manage to figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [glColorMask(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glColorMask.xml) before `glClearColor` and `glClear`.